# how to test a variable is a function handle or not in Matlab

Tags: matlab, validation

How to test/validate a variable is a function handle in matlab ?

it may be something like:

```
f=@(x)x+1
isFunctionHandle(f)
```

the `is*` build-in functions seems not support these kind testing? anyone know? many thanks

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19307726/2778484), which test for validity (having code to back it) as well as being a function handle.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The right way is indeed by means of an `is*` function, namely `isa`:

```
if isa(f, 'function_handle')
    % f is a handle
else
    % f is not a handle
end
```

**edit:** 
For completeness, I'd like to point out that using `class()` works for checking if something is a function handle. 
However, unlike `isa`, this doesn't generalize well to other aspects of MATLAB such as object-oriented programming (OOP) that are having an increasing impact on how MATLAB works (e.g. the plot functionality, the control toolbox, the identification toolbox, ... are heavily based on OOP).

For people familiar with OOP: `isa` also checks the super types (parent types) of the `x` object for `someClass`, while `strcmp(class(x), 'someClass')` obviously only checks for the exact type.

For people who don't know OOP: I recommend to use `isa(x, 'someClass')` instead of `strcmp(class(x), 'someClass')` as that is the most convenient (and commonly useful) behavior of the two.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `class()` function:

```
f = @(x)x+1

f = 

    @(x)x+1

>> class(f)

ans =

function_handle
```

(This is a string containing the text 'function_handle')