# Is it possible to test a function handle without try block?

Tags: matlab, function, handle, function-handle

Is is possible to replace the following code with something which does not use exceptions? The handle `x` is a provided handle. I want to test it for validity (having actual code to back the handle) before use.

```
x = @notreallyafunction;
try
   x();
catch 
   disp('Sorry function does not exist.');
end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To test function **handles** such as for screening out the bogus `x=@notreallyafunction` in your question, you can use the [`functions`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/functions.html) command to check the handle and get the referenced function's name, type (simple, nested, overloaded, anonymous, etc.), and location if it is defined in a file.

```
>> x = @notreallyafunction;
>> functions(x)
ans = 
    function: 'notreallyafunction'
        type: 'simple'
        file: ''
>> x = @(y) y;
>> functions(x)
ans = 
     function: '@(y)y'
         type: 'anonymous'
         file: ''
    workspace: {[1x1 struct]}
>>
```

The output of `functions` for a handle to a builtin (e.g. `x=@round`) will look just like a bogus function handle (`type` is `'simple'`).  The next step is to test the named function for existence:

```
>> x = @round;
>> fx = functions(x)
fx = 
    function: 'round'
        type: 'simple'
        file: ''
>> exist(fx.function)
ans =
     5
>> x = @notreallyafunction;
>> fx = functions(x)
fx = 
    function: 'notreallyafunction'
        type: 'simple'
        file: ''
>> exist(fx.function)
ans =
     0
```

However, you need to deal with anonymous functions since they fail existence test:

```
>> x = @(y) y;
>> fx = functions(x)
>> exist(fx.function)
ans =
     0
```

The solution is to first check the `type`.  If `type` is `'anonymous'`, then the check passes.  If the `type` is *not* `'anonymous'`, they you can rely on [`exist`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/exist.html) to check the function's validity.  Summing up, you could create a function like this:

```
% isvalidhandle.m Test function handle for a validity.
%   For example,
%     h = @sum; isvalidhandle(h) % returns true for simple builtin
%     h = @fake; isvalidhandle(h) % returns false for fake simple
%     h = @isvalidhandle; isvalidhandle(h) % returns true for file-based
%     h = @(x)x; isvalidhandle(h) % returns true for anonymous function
%     h = 'round'; isvalidhandle(h) % returns true for real function name
%   Notes:  The logic is configured to be readable, not compact.
%           If a string refers to an anonymous fnc, it will fail, use handles.
function isvalid = isvalidhandle(h)

if ~(isa(h,'function_handle') || ischar(h)),
    isvalid = false;
    return;
end

if ischar(h)
    if any(exist(h) == [2 3 5 6]),
        isvalid = true;
        return;
    else
        isvalid = false;
        return;
    end
end

fh = functions(h);

if strcmpi(fh.type,'anonymous'),
    isvalid = true;
    return;
end

if any(exist(fh.function) == [2 3 5 6])
    isvalid = true;
else
    isvalid = false;
end
```

Comment: No, this is incorrect. It returns true. I checked is* function but haven't found anything useful.

Comment: Hmm, still does not work... y=@sum; functions(x) returns the same result as functions(y)... you cannot distinguish

Comment: True, a handle to a builtin will look the same as a bogus function handle (both `type` of `simple`).  However, what you can do now is test if the function in `.functions` `exist`s.

Comment: @Dennis Jaheruddin - You call if for a function handle like `x=@str2num; isvalidhandle(x)`.  As the name implies, it is for function **handles** like the OP requested.  I'm sorry that wasn't clear.

Comment: @Dennis Jaheruddin - I just added function name input handling as well... to satisfy the hard to satisfy.  ;)

Comment: @chappjc I guess I was doing something wrong last time as it seemed like my solution passed the test and yours didn't. Your enhanced explanation has turned my vote!